# Android ListView overlapping

Tags: android, listview, layout, overlapping

Im trying to have LinearLayout below a ListView, which is pretty long, so the ListView is overlapping the layout below.. I have tried several ways, sometimes it looks good in the preview, but not in the emulator at runtime. This is my simple layout so far (had several others, that didnt work as well). Im getting mad to be stucked with this poor problem. Can anyone solve my puzzle please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="send"
        android:text="@string/odeslat" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="@string/reset" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/questionlst"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed to add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your footer `LinearLayout`. That's it! You get something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="send"
        android:text="hey" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="hey" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/questionlst"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Just checked it, it works in Android Studio.

Comment: well not for me - have you tried it with real device or emulator? Im using genymotion and when deployed it have the same problem

Comment: What does it look like? Can you upload a screenshot

Comment: I can, but there is nothing to see, just listview all over the screen filled with items. In android preview its fine, but not in the emulator (you can use AVD, should be the same result), and i dont have suitable android hardware to test it right now.

Comment: hmm...seems limiting number of items in that ListView does not help... its just showing few items but the rest of the screen is still filled up with ListView. Need to say the ListView is showed in a fragment via custom adapter but i guess it does not matter - should be some layout rendering problem

Comment: Can i shoot myself? I was inflating layout with different listview.. i had probably copied the base fragment construct as it is very similar layout as the other one and forgot to change it. So much time wasted! :-)

Ended up with similar layout Alex K provided, so this is considered as a correct answer, but can be done various ways